# HIVE CBO. Wrong results with Hive SQL query with MULTIPLE IN conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am running one SQL query in Hive and it gives different results with CBO enabled and disabled. The results are wrong when CBO is enabled (set hive.cbo.enable=true;).

**Prerequisites**:
Apache Hadoop 2.10.1 + Apache Hive 2.3.6 installed.
(I tried to reproduce the issue with Apache Hive 3+ version and Hadoop 3+ version and they work fine.)

Actions to reproduce:

**1) Create the table in Hive**

> CREATE TABLE `sample`(   `fname` string,   `sname` string,   `sid`
> string) ROW FORMAT SERDE
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' STORED AS
> INPUTFORMAT   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
> TBLPROPERTIES (   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1616020251');

**2) Insert some records in the table the below values**

> insert into sample values ("PQ", "F", "33");

> insert into sample values ("RK", "A", "11");

> insert into sample values ("AZ", "B", "22");

**3) Check the table**

> select * from sample;

```
PQ F 33
RK A 11
AZ B 22
```

**4) Run the below query. It should give 0 records, instead it gives all records**

> select fname from sample where sid in ('11') and sid in ('22');

```
PQ
RK
AZ
```

**5) The results are good when we disable cbo in Hive**

> set hive.cbo.enable=false;

> select fname from sample where sid in ('11') and sid in ('22');

OK
Time taken: 0.131 seconds

Comment: This is not really a question but a bug report. You describe the problem but it is not clear what you are expecting as an answer. For bug reports you can check https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HIVE/issues and if you don't find what you are looking for you can create a new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong results come from a wrong simplification in the HivePointLookupOptimizerRule [1]. This corresponds to the bug logged under  HIVE-21685 [2] that was fixed in versions >= 3.2.0.

As a workaround you can disable the respective rule by setting the respective property to false.

`set hive.optimize.point.lookup=false`

[1] https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/62834fbdd3bd4065413b59448759c6a25aa1dbf0/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/optimizer/calcite/rules/HivePointLookupOptimizerRule.java

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21685

Answer (score 0):

Datatype is String use INT

And the simplest solution is do not use CBO is problem still remains but if you still want to use check these things after altering the datatype

1.Privilages
2.Version control
3.auto tuned

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but your solution to change 'sid' from string to int didn't help. I created the same table but with 'sid' int, look at the results:
hive> select fname from sample1 where sid in (11) and sid in (22);
OK
AZ
PQ
RK
Time taken: 0.141 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> select fname from sample where sid in ('11') and sid in ('22');
OK
AZ
PQ
RK
Time taken: 0.2 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)

Answer (score 0):

Use in query to select multiple item

select fname from sample where sid in ('11','22');